# HttpResponseRedirect changes view but does not render template

Tags: python, django, http-redirect

I am new to Django and web programming in general, please don't make the answers too complicated. I have looked up the documentation and questions in here but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a form and after validating and saving the model to the database I want to redirect the user to a new page. My question is, how do I do it with HttpResponseRedirect(or even the shortcut redirect) correctly, because it redirects the view correctly, the url pattern gets called but when it reaches the view in the views.py something goes array. Why doesn't the template change but the view does?

Can somebody tell me where I am wrong, and how to fix it?

**views.py**

```
class CreateSuccess(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'login/successReg.html'

def CreateUser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newUser = form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('sucess/')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()

    return render(request, 'login/addUser.html', {'form':form})
```

**urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.LoginIndex.as_view(), name='loginIndex'),
    url(r'^create/', views.CreateUser, name='addUser'),
    url(r'^authenticate/', views.LoginUser.as_view(), name='loginUser'),
    url(r'^create/success/', views.CreateSuccess.as_view(), name='successReg'),
)
```

Comment: Could it because you've spelled `HttpResponseRedirect('sucess/')` wrongly and really meant `HttpResponseRedirect('create/success/)`?

Comment: @limelights no, its not that, when I use create/success/ it redirects me to create/create/success

Comment: @EcoGiko try `/success/` instead of `success/`. Notice the backslash in front.

Comment: @mariodev I tried it, it takes me to localhost:8000/success/ but success is not an app and I get a 404

Comment: @EcoGiko Sorry, I meant `/create/success/`, but I guess it gives you empty page as well.. right?

Comment: Where do you want it to go? Which view should it call? You don't have a URL `sucess/` so its not clear what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning an [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) object which constructs the required url for you

```
if form.is_valid():
    newUser = form.save()
    url = reverse('your_app:successReg') # Replace your_app with the name of your app
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

## More about `reverse()`:

`reverse(viewname)`

- viewname is either the function name *(either a function reference, or
  the string version of the name)* **which means that either you could make viewname a existing function in your `views.py` or either reference it by its string name in the `urls.py`**

It's always recommended to do it in the form `reverse('app_name : name_defined_in_urls')`

*Note: since your a beginner I dropped those optional `args and kwargs` parameters which are used if you want to redirect a user to dynamic webpage*

Comment: It works thanks, can you explain to me how the reverse works, I looked in the docs but I couldn't understand it at all.

Comment: @EcoGiko just of out curiosity, can you show us the generated success url? :)

Comment: @KDawG Thanks for the summary you helped me a lot, I had trouble with understanding how to use the args and kwargs but now I see those are not needed for now. :)

Comment: @EcoGiko your welcome and always remember to use reverse instead of using hardcoded url's because in case you wanted to change `/success/` to `/you_made_it/` you have to change all those url's but with `reverse()` it's automatic

Comment: @EcoGiko glad that you sort this out, although next time please provide more details, not mentioning the `login` app got everybody confused there ;)

Comment: @mariodev your answer is also true, but for hardcoded urls. Thanks for pointing out that in the urls.py I have to switch the places of created/ and created/success/ without it neither solution works.

Comment: @mariodev just for the fact hardcoding is **not recommended** plus enough details were provided by the OP although debugging django is as hard as it gets..

Comment: @KDawG The fact that it isn't possible to solve the issue just by harcoding the url, proves that there isn't enough details, not mentioning the typo. I have up-voted your answer as well, although it still doesn't say: *This is why your problem occurred, OP..* ;)